# привязка модели к пользователю asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, аутентификация

Допустим есть модель:

```
public class Book
{
    public int id;
    public string Title;
    ...
}
```

И как теперь сделать так что бы каждый пользователь имел набор Book, то есть каждый Book принадлежит одному пользователю и НЕ может быть показан другим.

Предполагаю что так:

```
 public class Book
 {
     public int id;
     public string Title;
     public ссылка на пользователя;
     ...
 }
 //Или наоборот - пользователь хранит ссылку на свои данные
```

Как это правильно(и безопасно) делать? (Пожалуйста с примером получения и изменения данных в контроллере).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас есть пустой Asp.Net MVC проект в котором вы при создании выбрали Individual User Accounts. Это вполне рабочая заготовка, в которой уже есть вход по логину-паролю, примеры страниц с представлениями. Начнём с неё.

Проверьте, что у вас есть модель пользователя:

```
// You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

И создайте заготовку модели для книг:

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Первое что нам нужно - это создать [отношение один-ко-многим](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php) между Book и  ApplicationUser (у одной книги может быть только один пользователь(владелец), у одного пользователя может быть множество книг). Этот момент относится к Entity Framework, выучите его внимательно, так как это база, от которой строятся более сложные вещи.

В класс Book добавляем:

```
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
```

В класс ApplicationUser добавляем:

```
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
```

И не забываем добавить в ApplicationDbContext

```
    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
```

(Тут по-хорошему момент как применить миграции - `Add-Migration CreateBookTable`, `Update-Database` но можете и не пользоваться)

В принципе, всё. Дальше можете создавать контроллеры и представления, которые хотите.

Допустим, для простоты у вас есть некоторый базовый контроллер, чтобы удобнее работать с базой:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        this.DbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected ApplicationDbContext DbContext { get; }
}
```

И вы хотите показать только книги какого-то определённого пользователя.

Контроллер:

```
public class BookController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult GetUserBook(int ownerID)
    {
        var books = this.DbContext.Book
            .Where(x => x.OwnerId == ownerID)
            .ToArray();

        return View(books);
    }
}
```

Представление:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Book[]

<h2>title</h2>

@foreach (var book in Model)
{
    @book.Title<br>
}
```

Или, если вы хотите, чтобы каждый видел только свои книги:

```
    public ActionResult MyBooks()
    {
        if (!this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return this.Redirect("/");

        var books = this.DbContext.Book
            .Where(x => x.OwnerId == this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>())
            .ToArray();

        return View(books);
    }
```

Отдельно рекомендую вот что. По умолчанию Microsoft для модели пользователя предлагает первичный ключ в виде строки... Однако иногда удобнее работать с int - поэтому можете отдельно потренироваться в смене типа для UserId. Вот есть [хорошая статья](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity) на эту тему.

Пример, который я привёл - учебный, в нём многие моменты сделаны по-простому.
Скажем, авторизацию проще проверить так:

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult MyBooks()
    {
        var books = this.DbContext.Book
            .Where(x => x.OwnerId == this.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>())
            .ToArray();

        return View(books);
    }
```

Можно отделить домен от слоя данных. Но вам пока достаточно такой тривиальный пример отработать.

Comment: То что надо! Спасибо!